# Mail using CDOSYS not working in asp classic application

Tags: asp.net, cdo.message, cdonts

I have been trying to send email using the CDOSYS object in ASP classic application but neither am I getting an error or email is sending. I am able to see the text "Mail was sent" but the mail is not reaching the destination. Not sure how to debug the issue. The code is as below

```
            <% 
        If Request.Form("Submit")="Send Email" Then 
        
            Dim objCDO
            Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            objCDO.Importance = 2
            objCDO.To = "as18831@ncr.com"
            objCDO.From ="as18831@ncr.com"
            objCDO.Subject = "Test Mail"
            objCDO.TextBody = "This is to test email functionality"
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            Response.write("<i>Mail was Sent</i><p>") 'You should always do this with CDONTS. 
            Set objCDO= Nothing
        %>
        
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title> Send Email </title
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email"/>
                </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: have you tried my answer yet?

Comment: It has been a week since I answered, I'm curious if you tried this yet, it should work.

Comment: I was using objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2, but seems some backend gateway version has been updated and the emails have stopped.

Comment: Ok but your code doesn't have the send mail command, is it in there and just not posted?  But yeah something changed the config probably has to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also SEND the email after you are done setting it up.
Add this code

```
objCDO.Send
```

BEFORE this line:

```
Response.write("<i>Mail was Sent</i><p>") 'You should always do this with CDONTS.
```

Comment: Wait a minute .. where is the END IF?  If there is no END IF .. it should of thrown an error when you ran it .. maybe you didn't include it ?  But it needs to be right after this line :  Set objCDO= Nothing

Comment: Just checking back, did you ever get this working after you added the change I listed above?